# Calling the http://x.x.x.x:10002/auth/user_token API returns a 404 page not found

Tags: chat, instant-messaging

I am currently integrating with a web service and have encountered an issue where a specific API call consistently returns a 404 Not Found error, despite other API endpoints functioning correctly and returning expected responses. This behavior is perplexing as it suggests a problem isolated to this particular endpoint rather than a systemic issue with the API or my integration approach.

To provide some context, the API in question is part of a larger suite of services, and I have been able to successfully interact with other endpoints without issue. This includes performing GET and POST requests, which have all responded with appropriate status codes and data. However, when attempting to call this specific endpoint, I am met with a 404 Not Found error every time, indicating that the server can't find the requested resource.

[image]
[image]